# How to remove the error hint on input focus in vueJS

Tags: forms, validation, vue.js, input

I'd like to remove the error when I have focus on my input.
Here is my input:

```
      <v-text-field
        v-model="models.codePostal"
        label="Code postal"
        :rules="regles.codePostal"
        :hint="this.models.communeResidence.codePostal!==''?`Pourrait être ${this.models.communeResidence.codePostal}`:''"
        hide-details="auto"></v-text-field>
```

I thought I could add

```
@focus="error=false"
```

But it doesn't work.
Does anybody have an idea? It may not be possible.
Thanks.

Comment: Try adding prop `hide-details="auto"` https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields#auto-hiding-details

Comment: It already is written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `reset` method on `focus` event.

```
<v-text-field
  @focus="reset()"
  ref="field"
  v-model="models.codePostal"
  label="Code postal"
  :rules="regles.codePostal"
  :hint="this.models.communeResidence.codePostal!==''?`Pourrait être ${this.models.communeResidence.codePostal}`:''"
  hide-details="auto"
></v-text-field>
```

```
 methods: {
    reset() {
      this.$refs.field.reset()
    }
```

Or `resetValidation()` method in the same way if you don't want to clear the field.

Comment: Thanks, it does work for the error, but it clears the input, what is not really good if the user only has to change a character.

Comment: @djcaesar9114 If you don't want to clear the field then use `resetValidation()` instead of `reset()`